# command line support for KIF for running tests on real device

Tags: kif-framework

I am using KIF to test my application. I want to start my tests from command line, I looked into the tool WaxSim, looks like it's for running the tests on a simulator. But is there a way to use KIF tests in continous Integration with the real device. It would be helpful if I can invoke the tests from command line which run in a real device. 
I know it is possible to do this with apple UI automation on ios5 beta version, but let me know if there is a way to do this in ios4.
Your help will be much appreciated.

-Teja

Answer (score 3):

From the [KIF google group](http://groups.google.com/group/kif-framework/browse_thread/thread/b8a932451162a2af)

> Right now, no, there isn't. Are there any particular device-only needs you have, or is it just on general principle? We're looking in to a way of doing device tests in CI, but it's a tough nut to crack. All of the frameworks for controlling devices are private.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well it would be ideal if I can test any device of my choice. But for now I am good if I can test one particular ipad. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Christian, if you are aware of any techniques to invoke the tests on a particular device, let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: I am not aware...I'm just a talking head.